# how to use freshbooks api in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, freshbooks-api

I am making app using freshbooks api in windows phone 7, I got problem when I add api link to add services reference, it ask for username and password, but when I enter username and password its ask again. can anyone tell me how to add api link to References?

or other trick to use freshbooks api in windows phone.

please help me 
thanks in advance.